# how to add previous rows for all dates based on some ID if data does not exist in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, date-arithmetic

I have a table like this in SQL:

| assetId | price | volume | netVolume | date | transactionDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-12 | 2023-05-12 10:32:10.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-12 | 2023-05-12 10:50:10.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 11:40:46.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 500 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 12:18:01.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-16 11:50:31.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 600 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-16 12:20:18.000 |

as you see for some days we may have multiple rows with same assetId (2023-05-12), or we may not have any thing.
I want to create a CTE to get a new table with this rules:

1. start from a @startDate and go to an @endDate, day by day
2. if there are multiple rows of the same assetId just pick the last one (based on transactionDateTime)
3. if for a specific date there is no row for an assetId, add the last one existing but change the  date to the current date, all other data must remain unchainged. do not add a row if you do not find any previous data.
   I managed to do the first part using below CTE, but I can not find a way to do the second part:

```
with CTE AS (
        SELECT assetId, rowNumber, price, volume, netVolume, date, transactionDateTime,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY td.assetId,td.date order by td.transactionDateTime desc) AS RN
        FROM transactiondData td
)
    SELECT assetId, rowNumber, price, volume, netVolume, date, transactionDateTime
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1 AND date >= @startDate AND date <= @endDate
    ORDER BY transactionDateTime;
```

at the end I must have a table like this, think @startDate = 2023-05-13 and @endDate = 2023-05-17 :

| assetId | price | volume | netVolume | date | transactionDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-13 | 2023-05-15 10:50:10.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-14 | 2023-05-15 10:50:10.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 10:50:10.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 11:40:46.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 500 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 12:18:01.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-16 11:50:31.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-15 10:50:10.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 600 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-16 12:20:18.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-05-16 11:50:31.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-05-15 10:50:10.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 600 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-05-16 12:20:18.000 |

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a a recursive query to generate the date range, then `cross join` it with the list of assets: this gives us possible combinations. Then, a simple approach to bring the corresponding transaction is `apply` with `top`:

```
with dates as (
    select @startDate dt
    union all select dateadd(day, 1, dt) from dates where dt < @endDate
)
select t.assetId, t.price, t.volume, t.netVolume, d.dt as date, t.transactionDateTime
from dates d
cross join (select distinct assetId from transactiondData) a
cross apply (
    select top (1) t.*
    from transactiondData t
    where t.date <= d.dt and t.assetId = a.assetId
    order by t.transactionDateTime desc
) t
order by d.dt, t.transactionDateTime
```

Note: since we use `cross apply`, "missing" rows that have no preceding transactions are skipped, because the subquery returns no rows.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bMWvi4_Y)**:

| assetId | price | volume | netVolume | date | transactionDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-13 | 2023-05-12 10:50:10.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-14 | 2023-05-12 10:50:10.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-12 10:50:10.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 11:40:46.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 500 | 2023-05-15 | 2023-05-15 12:18:01.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-12 10:50:10.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-16 11:50:31.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 600 | 2023-05-16 | 2023-05-16 12:20:18.000 |
| 1 | 200.00 | 100 | 200 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-05-12 10:50:10.000 |
| 3 | 300.00 | 100 | 100 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-05-16 11:50:31.000 |
| 2 | 200.00 | 100 | 600 | 2023-05-17 | 2023-05-16 12:20:18.000 |

Comment: @Ako: you don't need to add it to your existing query. This is a standalone query that does the job at once, starting directly from the sample data that you have shown. I updated the query and added a fiddle to my answer ,where you can see the query in action.